# How to bind to root context object signal from QML

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots

I'm creating QML application (QT 5.2)

Assume I have some object set as root context:

```
viewer.rootContext()->setContextObject(&view_model);
```

Now I want to bind to a signal of `view_model` from QML:

```
Connections {
    target: ??? WHAT SHOULD GO HERE ???
    onSignalStateChanged: console.log("signal")
}
```

Cannot figure out what should be the target.

**Important**: I don't want to use `setContextProperty`.

Comment: `Important: I don't want to use setContextProperty.` is there a good reason why?

Comment: The whole idea is in providing QML access to data_context as one entry point. So, when I use setContextProperty each time I want to use it I need add 'dataContext.' prefix, which is a little annoying.
As a result we used it to create 1 connection we needed ;)

Comment: "when I use setContextProperty each time I want to use it I need add 'dataContext.' prefix, which is a little annoying" - ummm, no you don't. Nothing mandates it. If In understand your issue, it is that you don't get an identifier to refer to for the connection syntax, because QML doesn't provide such for the context object. In which case you will have to use `setContextProperty` in order to obtain one.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood the documentation then. Anyway my goal was to avoid using 'setContextProperty'. My thoughts were: 'why do I need it, if I set the whole context object?'

Comment: Maybe you did. It is no coincidence there are tons of articles on exposing C++ objects to QML and they all involve the `setContextProperty()` method, and not a single one involves setting a context object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can't use `Connections` if you don't have access to object instance (via context property for example). But you still could use following:

```
function onSignal() {
    console.log( "signal" );
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    onSignalStateChanged.connect( onSignal );
}
```

Comment: do I understand correctly that you create a connection dynamically here as soon as object was created? I'll try if it works.

Comment: yes, exactly. I tried to find another ways, but with no success. I've spent some hours on finding it...

Comment: before this find I have to use `QQmlContext* context = m_quickViewPtr->rootContext();
context->setContextObject( this );
context->setContextProperty( QStringLiteral( "plugin" ), this );`